# How to extract all image urls from a nested object or json string

Tags: php

Given a JSON parsed object with deep nesting, I would like to extract an (array of) image(s) from a nested structure like this:

```
object: {
   type: "...",
   title:"...",
   description: {
     image:[
      src:"logo1.png",
      ...:...
     ]
   },
   somethingelse: {
      deeper:[
        {imageurl:"logo2.jpg"}
      ]
   }
}
```

how would I create a function that returns an array of images like this?

```
$images = getAllImagesFromObject(json_parse($jsonstring));
```

I do not know beforehand how deep the nesting will be and what the key will be, just any string beginning with http and ending on jpg, png and gif would be useful

I do not have any example since I do not know which method to use and I do not care what the key is so some var dump is also ok.

Perhaps even regex the jsonstring for `"http://....[jpg|gif|png]"` would be a solution

Comment: I guess recursion is the key.

Comment: Possibly. How do I recurse proper in PHP when I do not care what the keys are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. I did not test though.

```
function getAllImagesFromObject($obj) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($obj as $prop)
        if (is_array($prop) || is_object($prop))
            $result = array_merge($result, getAllImagesFromObject($prop));
        else if (preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$/', $prop))
            $result[] = $prop;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will the $result[]= append or replace?

Comment: Can you assist me to only return unique images? This does not seem to do what I think it should do: `if (!in_array($prop, $result)) $result[] = $prop;`

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is not possible to not store it if it is already in the array? My statement does not seem to do anything